# bash script: write string with double quotes and blanks to file

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I try to use *sed* to read a line from an ASCII file, parse it and write it slightly changed to a defined line number in an output file.

The line format in the input file is as follows:

```
linenumber:designator,"variable text content"
```

e.g.

```
3:string1,"this is text of string 1"
```

So the outfile should look as follows in line 3:

```
string1,"this is text of string 1"
```

The line includes the double quotes and the blanks. All old lines are moved one line down.

The user is responsible to provide a proper input file regarding the order of lines and has to consider that lines in the output file are moved down with each new line in the input file. The script does not know about any order except for the line number given in the input file.

A script shall read all lines and put the content of those lines into an outputfile at the given line numbers

- including double quotes and blanks
- without the line number part and the colon

The command I use successfully with the shell is e.g.:

```
sed -i '3istring1,"this is text of string 1"' outfile
```

No trouble with quotes, double quotes and blanks there.
Using the bash script

```
while read line           
do           
    linenum=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d:)
    linestr=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d:)
    sedcmd="sed -i '"
    sedcmd=${sedcmd}${linenum}
    sedcmd=${sedcmd}i
    sedcmd=${sedcmd}${linestr}
    sedcmd=${sedcmd}"' outfile"
    echo "---> $sedcmd"
    $sedcmd
done < script/new_records.txt
```

shows exactly the same *sed* command with *echo* but returns with:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

Apparently executing the sed command from within a bash script is different from executing it directly in the bash shell.
I tried a variety of escape sequences "\" before quotes, double quotes and blanks...but rather randomly, and neither of those was successful.

What do I have to do in order to write the string including blanks and double quotes to a specified line in a text file?

Comment: Please provide some example output. For example, given a data file `1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6` and an input file `2:foo,"bar"\n4:baz,"qux"`, what should the result be? Should it be different from the result of the same transformation with `4:baz,"qux"\n2:foo,"bar"`?

Comment: I edited the post to clarify the question. The user is responsible for a proper order in the inputfile.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the point I was getting at isn't clear from the edits. What I mean is: Does `4:baz,"qux"` mean that `baz,"qux"` should turn up as fourth line in the output, or that it should be inserted before what was originally the fourth line in the input? This makes a difference when a line was already inserted before that point. It is also important the other way around -- if a fourth line is inserted and then a second, the fourth will be pushed down. Is that desired? (Oh, and should it be inserted before or after the specified line?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'll give it a shot. If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, and if you're certain the code input file is not malformed, then

```
sed -i -f <(sed 's/:/i/' insertions.txt) datafile.txt
```

is the most straightforward way. This works because with an input specification of

```
number:text
```

all one has to do to is to replace the `:` with an `i` to get a sed command that says: "When handling line `number`, insert `text`". The `<()` bit is bash-style command substitution that expands to the name of a FIFO from which the output of the command can be read.

It might be prudent to guard against mistakes by saying something like

```
sed -i -f <(sed '/^[0-9]\+:/!d; s/:/i/' insertions.txt) datafile.txt
```

This removes all lines from `insertions.txt` that don't begin with a number followed by a colon because those are obviously broken.

Note that this all-in-one-go approach treats line numbers as they were in the input file. That is to say, given an insertions file with content

```
2:foo,"bar "
4:baz,"qux "
```

`baz,"qux "` will appear in line 5 of the output (before line 4 of the input). If this is not desired, sed will have to be called multiple times to handle each insertion individually, as in

```
while read insertion; do
  sed -i "${insertion/:/i}" datafile.txt
done < insertions.txt
```

`${insertion/:/i}` is another bashism that replaces the first `:` in a shell variable with `i` and expands to the result, i.e., if `insertion=1:2:3`, then `${insertion/:/i}` is `1i2:3`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need the loop to call `sed` multiple times. Except for the `-f` in the last example which is expecting a file rather than a shell variable, that's what I need. Since the files getting changed are under version control and the result can be easily checked/reverted, I don't use any checks.

Comment: Oh, right. I had a `<()` substitution there before I had the idea with `${//}` and forgot to remove the `-f`. It's fixed now.

Comment: As for checks: your scenario sounds as though hackery is relatively unlikely, but be aware that GNU sed can be made to run shell commands. If the insertions file comes from an untrustworthy source (such as *that guy* at the office), shenanigans can occur. If I were you, I'd probably put the sed command between `if [[ "$insertion" =~ ^[0-9]+: ]]; then` and `fi`, just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Assuming OutFile exist and have enough line
while read ThisLine           
 do
    LineNum=$(echo "${ThisLine}" | cut -f1 -d ":" )
    echo "${ThisLine##*:}" > /tmp/LineContent.txt

    sed -i -n "${LineNum} !{p;b;};r /tmp/LineContent.txt" OutFile
 done < script/new_records.txt
```

Not the best thing because you assume lot of issue like enough line in outfile, no problem reading the line (what about escaped char in quoted string, ...) could occur